# can we customize catch block to include our logging codes, every time whenever we surround with try/catch?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, visual-studio, try-catch

whenever we need to exception handling, we will surround with try/catch block, but when we surround try/catch block, Visual studio will give like this.

```
try
{
}
Catch (Exception e)
{
  // here we need to write code for logging every time manually. 
}
```

1. can we automate the process, of catch block with our own exeception logging code which will be the same all time. what i mean, whenever i surround method, can include our own logging codes into exception block automatically ? is there any tool or work around.
2. the main reason asking for these, many jr.developer will not handle exception or logging, though we review code, what i tought will make automation whenever we surround try/catch block in our method which need to be logging, in catch  block it will include all our logging code.

may be like this

```
Catch(Exception e ) // i am telling it for a function, not as global catch handler. 
{                   // logging at method/function level. for method which we need to log
  ourLogging obj = new Ourlogging(); // these two line should added automaticaly, 
  obj.Publish(e);                   //as when user surrounded with try/catch block ? 
  obj = null; 
}
```

1. if is there any visual studio addon or some work around, or if any body have some tool or script to achive this task it would be helpful, to many fellow developer.

i hope every one understood my question.

Comment: It looks like you want to log and __swallow__ exceptions on a large scale. You may have your reasons to do that but in general it is not a good idea. A good strategy is to catch exceptions at the root of your call stacks and react to them accordingly (including logging). Doing it like this shouldn't require so many exception handlers that you need automation to create them.

Comment: @MartinLiversage not at global, i am telling in every method. where we write functions. i am telling about some functions

Comment: Well, I smell an exception anti-pattern here, but maybe there is something I don't know about your architecture? http://devlicio.us/blogs/billy_mccafferty/archive/2007/11/30/exception-handling-anti-pattern.aspx

Comment: we use 3 tier architecture. what i want i need to put logging code whenever we surround with  try/catch block in a method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you need to edit the code snippet provided by Visual Studio. You can do this by modifying the `try.snippet` file typically located here:

`C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC#\Snippets\1033\Visual C#`

The default contents of this file are as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<CodeSnippets  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/2005/CodeSnippet">
    <CodeSnippet Format="1.0.0">
        <Header>
            <Title>try</Title>
            <Shortcut>try</Shortcut>
            <Description>Code snippet for try catch</Description>
            <Author>Microsoft Corporation</Author>
            <SnippetTypes>
                <SnippetType>Expansion</SnippetType>
                <SnippetType>SurroundsWith</SnippetType>
            </SnippetTypes>
        </Header>
        <Snippet>
            <Declarations>
                <Literal>
                    <ID>expression</ID>
                    <ToolTip>Exception type</ToolTip>
                    <Function>SimpleTypeName(global::System.Exception)</Function>
                </Literal>
            </Declarations>
            <Code Language="csharp"><![CDATA[try 
    {           
        $selected$
    }

    catch ($expression$)
    {
        $end$
        throw;
    }]]>
            </Code>
        </Snippet>
    </CodeSnippet>
</CodeSnippets>
```

You just need to update the try/catch block between the `<Code>` nodes.

Answer (score 1):

You could write a class to wrap the try catch code, passing in delegates to execute within that the try block, something like:

```
    public void ExecuteTryCatch<T>(Action<T> action, T genericParameter)
    {
        try
        {
            action.Invoke(genericParameter);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            //Do Logging
        }
    }
```

There is probably a much cleaner way than this but I would be concerned of a code smell because you get into the habit of catching all exceptions the same. In fact I would heavily advise doing anything like this, the only time I have done something similar was in a single class where I was calling different web service methods and had a single method to handle cleaning up the connection on different types of exceptions.  But that was contained to one class, all methods were performing something similar and they all wanted to handle exceptions exactly the same.

You didn't state whether this was for windows/web but you should easily be able to have a application level exception handler which would catch all **Unhandled** exceptions to perform your application wide logging.

Comment: its web application..can u explain what code smell means here :p?

Comment: You could look at Elmah, it's an open source library for application wide logging, I have used it in a few projects with good success, easy to integrate and configure.
http://code.google.com/p/elmah/

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you looking for an AOP solution, so you can apply an aspect to your method and your try/catch custom code is put "automatically" (in fact, injected by a tool).

Take a loot at these examples from Postsharp, a great tool for AOP in .NET:  http://www.sharpcrafters.com/postsharp/documentation. Your junior developers can simply put a custom attribute at the method you want to have its exception handled.

Answer (score -2):

Are you familiar with [finally (link to MSDN)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zwc8s4fz.aspx)?

Finally blocks are guaranteed by .NET to execute every time, whether or not an exception is thrown.

It's not automated, per se, but it's simple enough to standardize your logging code and paste it in a finally block where needed.

Comment: i know finally, i am asking about automation, how to customization. placing log in finally is not good. it will log everything :-/

Comment: Through use of variables you can limit logging to only when exceptions are thrown - but I recognize that this isn't a solution you're interested in.  Best of luck finding something that better fits your requirements.

Comment: Well, if you're going to call me a liar then I'll be happy to downvote so we're all honest again.  Good day...

Comment: I think it's a bit misleading to state that code is guaranteed to be executed in a finally block, it really depends upon the exception that was thrown, some exceptions are unrecoverable, I believe StackOverflowException is a common exception to cause this, along with the process being killed and of course the machine actually powering down.

Comment: @PaulieWaulie You are correct - but in that case no logging would happen anyway.  More accurate wording would be "finally is guaranteed to execute during normal execution and in the event of any handled exception" but I didn't see the need to spell out the details.

Comment: @MattT I didn't mean that to seem like I was having a pop at you, I just personally feel that some people may glance over words like guaranteed and get the wrong impression, stating the caveat, even briefly can be helpful to others, that was all :0).